# can't load json-query package

Tags: javascript, json-query

In Windows `cmd`, I typed

```
npm install json-query
```

It seemed successfully by typing:

```
npm -v json-query
```

It said version of `8.5.5`.

In my HTML, I did

```
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="myscripts.js">  <!-- myscript.js is where I put my JavaScripts-->
```

In `myscripts.js`  :

```
function someFunc(){
    var jsonQuery = require('json-query');
    var result = jsonQuery('traff_volume[gate=Ma Wan]', {
        data: obj
        });
    console.log(result);
}
```

The error message showed:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "json-query" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (require.js:5:1067)
    at Object.o [as require] (require.js:5:11053)
    at requirejs (require.js:5:14737)
    at creat_traffic_table (myscripts.js:175:19)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.el.onclick (myscripts.js:126:9)
```

Is there any other dependancy or setting I need to do?

Comment: so... you have installed `json-query` globally? Also... the error seems to be happening after a `click` somewhere... when is this `require('json-query');` supposed to happen?

Comment: I guess it is globally, I am not sure indeed. I use VSCode to do it. Yes you are right, it is supposed to happen after a `click` action.  So I need to put `require` somewhere at the top of `myscripts.js` ?

Comment: There must be a network call to fetch `json-query`. can you check in the networks, if there is any and if it has succeeded?

Comment: Also take a look at the link to [error docs](https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded)

Comment: There is an example [here](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages) which can help you load `json-query` from a CDN itself... Just another option.